# jQuery.load() loaded content disappeared

Tags: jquery, load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <title>Temponary Rush</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='web/css/login.css'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='left'>
                levá strana
            </div>
            <div id='center'>
                <form method='POST'>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button id='playasguest'>Play as guest</button>
                                <button id='login'>Login</button>
                                <button id='register'>Register</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id='act-login'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text' placeholder='Nick'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type='submit' value='Play as guest'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id='right'>
                pravá strana
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#playasguest').click(function(){
                   $('#act-login').load('web/content/playasguest.html');            
               });
               $('#login').click(function(){
                   $('#act-login').load('web/content/logintable.html');
               });
                $('#register').click(function(){
                   $('#act-login').load('web/content/registertable.html');
               });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Hi guys, I have this problem.
When I click lets say play as guest, it will appear and instantly disappear.
I can see it only when I am clicking in it really fast.
Console gives me no error so far.
I tried to add function to check if its loaded and it is. File is okay so I don't know.

Comment: `<button>`s act by default as submit buttons (`type="submit"`) ;)

Comment: so ? how can I fix that ?

Comment: One way would be to define them as `type="button"`

Comment: @FilipBartoš add `type="button"` to their HTML, or hook to the `submit` event of the `form` and call `preventDefault()` on the event thats raised.

Comment: Thanks guys I will use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use preventDefault() Event Method

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
                       $('#playasguest').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#act-login').load('web/content/playasguest.html');            
                       });
                       $('#login').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                           $('#act-login').load('web/content/logintable.html');
                       });
                        $('#register').click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                           $('#act-login').load('web/content/registertable.html');
                       });
                    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html dir='ltr'>
 <head>
   <title>Temponary Rush</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='web/css/login.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id='container'>
           <div id='left'>
                        levá strana
                    </div>
                    <div id='center'>
                        <form method='POST'>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button id='playasguest'>Play as guest</button>
                                        <button id='login'>Login</button>
                                        <button id='register'>Register</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table id='act-login'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type='text' placeholder='Nick'>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type='submit' value='Play as guest'>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div id='right'>
                        pravá strana
                    </div>
                </div>
                
             
            </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!